# Error when integrating Appsheet with Apigee

Tags: apigee, google-appsheet

I have created a basic CRUD application and Open API spec.

API Spec: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bilbin-john/Apps/main/student2.yaml

In Appsheet am able to perform list and create operations.
However Edit and Delete is failing with error: `Unable to update row in table 'students'. → Apigee: Row ID not found`

I do not want the Row ID column. How do I resolve this issue.